# Require client-side

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

Bom dia.

Na empresa onde trabalho, existe uma especie de require client-side para importar npm sem que ele exista na página. É usado para inserção de scripts de formulário dentro da página. O código fica assim:

```
require(['jquery'], function () {
    //código com jquery
});
```

E dentro do escopo desta função, o jquery funciona mesmo quando não há jquery na página.

Como isso é feito? Busquei na internet alguns plugins server-side e client-side, mas nenhum deles se encaixa ou funciona desta forma.